# Не запускается AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-intent, исключения

Из класса, не наследующегося от Activity, вызывается класс с AlertDialog'ом (в случае исключения):

```
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Alert.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
```

Сам класс обрабатывается без ошибок, однако диалог не вызывается:

```
public class Alert extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alert_activity);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Alert.this);
    builder.setTitle("Внимание!")
            .setMessage("Нет соединения с сервером, попробуйте позже.")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton("ОК",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
}
```

Как быть?

Comment: замените context на getBaseContext()

Comment: Зачем создавать Activity только для того, чтобы показать диалог?? Почему не создать его прямо в "классе, не наследующемся от Активити"?    
new AlertDialog.Builder(Context context) - конструктору ведь и не требуется Activity.

Comment: Это не работает, если засунуть в "класс, не наследующийся от Активити", поэтому я попробовал сделать отдельное Activity. 

А насчет "замените context на getBaseContext()" не совсем понятно, что именно и где заменять? В качестве context я передаю класс-наследник Activity при вызове "класса, не наследующегося от Активити"

Возможно проблема связана с AsyncTask

Comment: Проблема решена полной переделкой кода

Comment: `System.exit(0);` надеюсь это удалил в новой версии? :)